# C++: Parsing patterned string, probably by Regular Expression

Tags: c++

I have a string in the below format and want to parse this one and do some string manipulations with it and return back the result or throw back an exception. ALL C++.

Below is the format of the string to be parsed

" AND  LIKE "" AND  LIKE "" AND so on..."

I was thinking of going in for something like Regular Expression which can handle this. But, i am a naive in this area.

Any ideas from you geniuses would be great.

Comment: Can you describe the format more exactly? And what kind of object do you want the parser to return?

Comment: 3 possible questions: are RE's a good solution?, what is a usable C++ RE library? (e.g. boost::RE), what RE do I need?  Which question are you asking?

Comment: If your grammar is regular you can use regex, SQL for instance is CFG. If you grammar is so simple as you discribed than you may use "split" function

Answer (score 0):

Below is an sample query and the expected output:

Strvalue = " 1=1  AND fSPRNumber LIKE "%"12"%" AND rRequestedFor.rOrganization.fName LIKE "%"abcd"%""

Expected:
All the values within the double quotes, after the LIKE, to be extracted and then processed.
E.g.:
       "%"12"%"
       "%"abcd"%""

I should be able to do this for any number of AND and/or LIKE clauses in the query.

Also, suggest if there is simpler way of doing it.